# hostname failing to resolve in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dns, bind9

I have a DNS server configured but the hostname is failing to resolve. I keep getting these error when running `host`:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# host hostname
Host hostname not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

And I also get bad command output after I run `hostname -f`:

```
[root@ns1 ~]# hostname -f
/etc/host.conf: line 1: bad command `154.70.157.36 ns1.suretelcom.co.ug hostname'
suretelcom.co.ug
```

What could be my error?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're putting content that *should* be in `/etc/hosts` into `/etc/host.conf`.

- `/etc/host.conf` is a file [that defines how the `host` command should work](http://www.linfo.org/etc_host_conf.html).  It is not a lookup database.  On CentOS by default, my systems only contain a single line:

  `multi on`
- `/etc/hosts` is [the lookup database where you should be putting the definitions of various hosts](http://www.linfo.org/etc_hosts.html), like:

  `154.70.157.36 ns1.suretelcom.co.ug hostname`

Your syntax looks ok, so if you get the right content into the right files, I think you'll get the results you expect.